# How to change textview text in custom alert dialog?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

**Dears this is my code, textview text could not be change ?.....**

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(User.this);
 LayoutInflater inflater = (User.this).getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the
    // dialog layout
    rname=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null).findViewById(R.id.tv_frname);
    fname=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null).findViewById(R.id.tv_fname);
    ftype=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null).findViewById(R.id.tv_ftype);
    fdetails=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null).findViewById(R.id.tv_fdetails);
    remail=(TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null).findViewById(R.id.tv_email);

    rname.setText(Srname);
    ftype.setText(Sftype);
    fdetails.setText(Sfdetails);
    remail.setText(Ssremail);
    fname.setText(Sfname);
    builder.setTitle("Food Details");
   // builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fooditemview, null))
    // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }

            });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();

    }
```

errors in logcat is

```
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):  Process:com.example.foodadviser, PID: 11065
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at com.example.foodadviser.User.FoodDetailsDialog(User.java:457)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at com.example.foodadviser.User.access$2(User.java:440)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at com.example.foodadviser.User$1.onItemSelected(User.java:87)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
02-24 14:19:58.846: E/AndroidRuntime(11065):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 14:19:59.043: D/dalvikvm(11065): threadid=17: interp stack at 0x60b74000
```

i tried this please help me. How to fix this problem.
Is this even possible without trashing everything and just creating a custom view (which I am very averse to trying to tackle this fresh into Android programming...)

Comment: No need to inflate layout again-2, just do it once and use it to access View's and for passing same object to setView method

Comment: Check the id of all TextViews in your layout fooditemview once again. It seems at least one of your TextView is initializing with a textview id that is not available in the fooditemview layout.